# Tabs on top and bottom of the screen

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm trying to build a view that will have standard tabs on the bottom and action bar tabs in the upper part of the screen.
I've tried using `FragmentTabHost` together with `TabLayout` but with no success since they both call `getSupportFragmentManager()` so one cancels another.
I've also thought about using deprecated `TabLayoutActivity` but I'm using AppCompat theme so all my activities have to inherit `AppCompatActivity`.

Is there a way for bottom tab to start activities and upper one fragments, or at least both starting fragments that work?

[image: Exanmple]

Comment: Have you implemented it? I need to do this with multiple back stack navigation like Instagram Android application. Please tell me if you found any way to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can have 2 framelayouts (bottom,middle).

On bottom framelayout you will have a fragment with buttons as tabs, when you click on each button you will send back to activity which button clicked.

On middle framelayout you can have a TabLayout fragment and if you prefer also 1 fragment for each tab in the tablayout.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is to use `getChildFragmentManager()` available in the support library to have a Fragment inside another Fragment.
The outer one with `FragmentTabHost` can be controlled by main fragment manager `getFragmentManager()` and inner one with `TabLayout` by child fragment manger `getChildFragmentManager()`.
Here's an example with [nested fragments](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/Nested).
Still looking for a viable solution with Activity and a Fragment.